# How to detect parent widget close in PyQT?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've created a `QVBoxLayout` which contains multiple other widgets. When the parent window of the `QVBoxLayout` (currently a `QDialog`) is closed, I need all the widgets to be notified of the close event so they may delete temporary files. Is this idiomatic and how could I do it?

In my application, I have subclassed `QLabel` with a class that allows me to store a reference to the temporary file that makes up it's pixMap. When it's parent window is closed, I need to be able to close the file.

**EDIT:** I've already tried handling the close event:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.imgFile.close()
```

Comment: over-ride the `CloseEvent` of the parent widget to emit a signal and connect that signal to functions in the child widgets that do the clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ways you can accomplish this, using what I would think is idiomatic Qt.

1. Use the `closeEvent` on the parent to directly perform the cleanup on each child.
2. Use the `destroyed` signal on the parent to call the cleanup indirectly on each child
3. Emit a custom signal from the `closeEvent` on the parent, wired directly to the cleanup on the child.

Options #2/#3 are commented out in the following:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWidget(QtGui.QDialog):

    # Option #3 - Custom signal
    closing = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        for i in xrange(5):
            label = ResourceLabel('label%02d' % i)
            self.layout.addWidget(label)

            # option #2
            # Let a signal trigger the cleanup on the children
            # self.destroyed.connect(label.close)

            # option #3
            # Use a custom signal emitted from the closeEvent,
            # wired directly to the cleanup slot on the object
            # self.closing.connect(label.close)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "Closing main window"

        # option #1
        # if you want to trigger a cleanup specifically when
        # this widget is closed, as opposed to destroyed
        for i in xrange(self.layout.count()):
            item = self.layout.itemAt(i)
            widget = item.widget()       
            if widget:
                try:
                    widget.close()
                except:
                    pass

        # Or Option #3 - emit a custom signal
        self.closing.emit()

        super(MainWidget, self).closeEvent(event)


class ResourceLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResourceLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.aResource = "FOO"

    def close(self):
        print "Cleaning up", self
        self.aResource = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWidget()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()
```

Either one will work. I like option #2 better, because it lets the parent window stay a bit agnostic of its children, and simply connects the right ones at the time of their construction, to the slot that will clean them up.

The reason for option #3 was based on your comments below. In your code that you posted, my guess is that your dialog is not really being deleted at all. It still exists and is just being closed. So the close event should be triggered but not a destroy signal. So option 3 places a custom signal into the closeEvent that mimics exactly what the `destroyed` signal would do if it were being deleted.

Comment: Option #2 didn't work for me. I never receive the destroyed signal.

Comment: Can you pastebin your code here so I can look? My example should work fine.

Comment: https://github.com/liamzebedee/misc/blob/master/gimg/gimg.py#L81 is the line in which I am using it.

Comment: It seems from your code that you aren't actually letting the dialog get destroyed, because you [parent it to another widget](https://github.com/liamzebedee/misc/blob/master/gimg/gimg.py#L129). Even though the python object goes out of scope, the object still exists and is probably just being hidden and not destroyed (my guess). What you might need is a 3rd option, I will update my answer.